# Is this question opinion based?

Tags: discussion, off-topic-questions

I'd prefer to get a... well, opinion, before I post this question on the main site. It is: To what extent are the development of language and evolution by natural selection analogous? Or, what similarities (and what differences) can we draw between the two processes. Is any question asking about similarities or differences going to be broad/opinion-based?

Comment: If you mean the original development of language, well no one really knows anything about it.

Comment: No, I mean the development of language at all, whether original or modern.

Comment: Well, Darwin used language change as an example of natural selection, and generally most linguists would agree with him. Of course, it's not Mendelian but LaMarckian evolution; however Darwin wasn't concerned with that, because Mendel's work wasn't discovered till after Darwin's death. But the question is incomplete; it should include culture, which is how humans encounter their environment. Language is just how they talk (and maybe sometimes think) about it.

Comment: BTW, thanks for a wonderfully unanswerable question title. Like "This sentence is true".